# Shifting Coordinates Using array reversal

Tags: java

My problem is this: I store coordinates in rows (initialized by an array myCoordinateArray), and the coordinates in these rows either have to be shifted to the back or shifted to the front.

Now, my program worked before, but I am trying a different method now with regards to shifting my coordinates to the front using a array reversal method. Problem is, I only get half the output I need. So it seems not all my coordinates are being outputted.

I am working with classes.

EDIT*** I have decided to post my full program to help people get an idea on perhaps why with addCoordinateRowFront (Method 1) my program 100% works, but with addCoordinateRowFront (Method 2 - array reversal) my program no longer works. I really have no idea why this is the case and I really cannot find the problem. Hope someone will be able to shed some light. I very much appreciate the help!

Here is my Main Pirate Class

```
package Pirate;


import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;


import ui.UIAuxiliaryMethods;



public class Pirate {

    CoordinateRow newCoordinateRow;
    Coordinate singleCoordinate;
    Coordinate newCoordinate;
    int singleCoordinateX;
    int singleCoordinateY;
    PrintStream out;
    String position;



    Pirate() {

        out = new PrintStream(System.out);
        newCoordinateRow = new CoordinateRow();
        position = "front";
    }



    void separateCoordinateRows(Scanner coordinateDataScanner) {

        String[] coordinateDataStringArray = coordinateDataScanner.nextLine().split("="); //Split line of input at = into an array of strings

        for(int i = 0; i < coordinateDataStringArray.length; i++) {

            Scanner individualCoordinateRowScanner = new Scanner(coordinateDataStringArray[i]);

            placeCoordinateRow(isolateIndividualCoordinates(individualCoordinateRowScanner));
        }

    }


    CoordinateRow isolateIndividualCoordinates(Scanner scannerInput) {

        CoordinateRow newCoordinateRow = new CoordinateRow();

        String[] individualCoordinateStringArray = scannerInput.nextLine().split(" "); //further split the array of strings into smaller array of strings at white-spaces.

        for(int i = 0; i < individualCoordinateStringArray.length; i++) {

            Scanner individualCoordinateScanner = new Scanner(individualCoordinateStringArray[i]);

            newCoordinateRow.addSingleCoordinateToBack(adjustedCoordinates(individualCoordinateScanner)); //add new coordinates back into rows. 

        }

        return newCoordinateRow;
        
    }



    Coordinate adjustedCoordinates(Scanner individualCoordinateScanner) {

        String[] individualCoordinateStringArray = individualCoordinateScanner.nextLine().split(","); //split array of strings into even smaller array of strings at (,). 

        for(int i = 0; i < individualCoordinateStringArray.length; i++) {

            singleCoordinateX = Integer.parseInt(individualCoordinateStringArray[0]);

            singleCoordinateY = Integer.parseInt(individualCoordinateStringArray[1]);

            singleCoordinate = new Coordinate(singleCoordinateX, singleCoordinateY); //convert existing coordinates to new coordinates

        }

        return singleCoordinate;

    }


    CoordinateRow placeCoordinateRow(CoordinateRow rowOfCoordinates) { //add rows of new coordinates either to the front or behind.

        if(position.equals("front")) {

            newCoordinateRow.addCoordinateRowFront(rowOfCoordinates);

            position = "back";


        } else if(position.equals("back")) {

            newCoordinateRow.addCoordinateRowBack(rowOfCoordinates);

            position = "front"; 
        }

        return newCoordinateRow;
    }



    void printCoordinateRows() {


        for(int i = 0; i < newCoordinateRow.numberOfElements; i++) {

            out.printf("%d, %d\n", newCoordinateRow.newCoordinateArray[i].coordinateX, newCoordinateRow.newCoordinateArray[i].coordinateY);
        }

    }


    void start() {

        Scanner newCoordinateInputData = UIAuxiliaryMethods.askUserForInput().getScanner();

        separateCoordinateRows(newCoordinateInputData);

        printCoordinateRows();

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
        new Pirate().start();
    }

}
```

Here is my CoordinateRow class code:

```
public class CoordinateRow {

    static final int MAX_NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS = 250;
    //want to create a new row class, that can store up to max 250 elements, but can store lower than this

    Coordinate[] newCoordinateArray;
    int numberOfElements;
    
    
    CoordinateRow() {

        newCoordinateArray = new Coordinate[MAX_NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS];
        numberOfElements = 0;
        
    
}


void addCoordinateRowBack(CoordinateRow rowOfCoordinates) {

    for(int i = 0; i < rowOfCoordinates.numberOfElements; i++) {

        newCoordinateArray[numberOfElements] = rowOfCoordinates.newCoordinateArray[i];

        numberOfElements++;


    }

}


void addSingleCoordinateToBack(Coordinate singleCoordinate) {

    newCoordinateArray[numberOfElements] = singleCoordinate;

    numberOfElements++;

} 



void addCoordinateRowFront(CoordinateRow rowOfCoordinates) {
    
    Coordinate[] newArray = new Coordinate[rowOfCoordinates.numberOfElements];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < rowOfCoordinates.numberOfElements; i++) {
        
        newArray[i] = rowOfCoordinates.newCoordinateArray[rowOfCoordinates.numberOfElements -i - 1];
    
    }
    
}
```

}

This is my Coordinate Class

```
package Pirate;

public class Coordinate {

    static final int COORDINATE_X_TECTONIC_SHIFT = 1;
    static final int COORDINATE_Y_TECTONIC_SHIFT = 0;

    int coordinateX;
    int coordinateY;

    Coordinate(int coordinateX, int coordinateY) {

        this.coordinateX = coordinateX + COORDINATE_X_TECTONIC_SHIFT;
        this.coordinateY = coordinateY + COORDINATE_Y_TECTONIC_SHIFT;

    }


}
```

It seems to be going wrong with my reversal method (addCoordinateRowFront) as my other methods work fine with the last program I tried.

Not sure why this is the case.

For clarification, when I use this method for shifting coordinates to the front instead. My program works

```
void addCoordinateRowFront(CoordinateRow rowOfCoordinates) {

        for(int j = rowOfCoordinates.numberOfElements; j > 0; j--) {

            for(int i = numberOfElements; i > 0; i--) {

                newCoordinateArray[i] = newCoordinateArray[i-1];

            }
            newCoordinateArray[0] = rowOfCoordinates.newCoordinateArray[j-1];

            numberOfElements++;
        }

    }

}
```

But I would much prefer row reversal to work as I understand it better.

When I print in my addCordinateRowFront method to see what is going on, this is what I get:

```
Pirate.Coordinate@512ddf17
Pirate.Coordinate@2c13da15
Pirate.Coordinate@77556fd
Pirate.Coordinate@368239c8
Pirate.Coordinate@9e89d68
7, 3
4, 2
10, 6
5, 3
10, 8
```

Comment: Let me know if I understood, you just want to shift right an array, right? I think you just need the inner for loop of the method you said it works (but check with array's size).

Comment: The bottom method works. All i want to do is take  my coordinate row, and shift the coordinates to the front. But I am wondering if this can also be done with the reversal method.

Comment: you mean, increasing the counter instead of decreasing? You might be overwriting values that way...

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Sorry! The coordinates in the row have to remain, they simply just need to be shifted front or back depending on the condition

Comment: I don't understand why 1) numberOfElements is a separate field as I have the impression that it's always the size of the 'newCoordinateArray' array? and 2) why you are using arrays when you can make your life easy and use a collection such as ArrayDeque

Comment: I can only use arrays in this unfortunately. The numberOfElements keeps track of how many elements i have in my myCoordinateArray. So Basciaslly, I fill it with coordinates, I then take that row and shift everything to the front or back.

Comment: To keep track of the size of the array, you can use the property length of the array itself

Comment: Yes but the array that i create is simply just to store coordinates that I get from my input. Then i need to shift them

Comment: There is something between my two versions of addCoordinateRowFront method that I cant spot that is causing one to work and one to make the program fail

Comment: In the method that is "wrong", you start putting the last element to the first position, and goes on the loop until you reach the middle part of the array, where you start doing useless copies. That method erases part of the array and duplicates the end of it. Try debugging to see the behavior.

Comment: So my reversal method is incorrect? Any pointers to help solve that? Many thanks!

Comment: To shift right, you need to start the loop from the end of the array, and copy the previous element (i-1) to the current one (i).

Comment: By shift right do you mean shift everything forward? I still get the same problem .

Comment: still lost. Still trying to figure out why this reversal does not like the program